# Best time to tell your manager that you are quitting?

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, hiring-process, new-job, job-change

I know that is best to keep it a secret when you are having interviews for another job until your new job is officially confirmed from your new employer. But what if your new employer wants to get your current's manager advice as a recommendation, before he takes his final decision? Should I deny or accept?

The above scenario happened to a friend of mine but the new job was in the same company as the previous job. Could this happen when moving from one company to another, and then what should someone do? Tell my current manager that I am looking for a new job and let the two (old and potential new manager) discuss if I am suitable for the new job?

Comment: Hypothetical question= - not answering it. Let us know when you actually have a new employer who wants to do this nonsense.

Comment: I paid attention to your specific non-problem, and then downvoted it, not because similar questions exist (I never downvote for that reason, btw), but because you are asking for solutions to a problem which nobody has.

Comment: what is the difference if this in actual scenario that i am facing. i could just lie and just tell you that this is something that i am currently facing. then would you have a reason to downvote?

Comment: For an internal transfer, it is quite natural for the new manager to ask the old manager's recommendation. However, you are extrapolating that to another situation, where it is extremely unlikely to occur. In other words, you are saying, "this situation occurred in case A, what if it happened in case B?" when the situation doesn't apply to case B at all.

Comment: That aside, I don't really understand the point you are trying to make. Votes are cast based on the contents of the post. If you hadn't mentioned that this is an imaginary situation, I would have no way of knowing it was, and so the question of "downvoting it because it is hypothetical" doesn't arise at all. Now you ask, "what if I hadn't mentioned this?", which is *another* hypothetical problem which too nobody cares about. Remember life is short, I would recommend you spend more of it working on real problems than creating imaginary problems and trying to solve them.

Comment: This is why it is good to develop different "groups" of contacts in different industries, or keep in touch with some profs you worked with at university. Having your current manager provide a review is just suicide in terms of your career. If you don't get the job, you'll be fired soon is my guess. Also, expect your company to start analysing time taken off (ie: sick days) with greater scrutiny. If they feel you've used those instead of vacation days for entertaining job offers, you could be sent packing with no severance. Not cool.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would refuse.  The hiring manager is either naive or does not care about putting your current job at risk.

What happens if your current boss gives you a not-good-enough review?  You wouldn't get hired at the new place and you'd have a big red target painted on your back at the old one.

For what it's worth, I don't think this would happen in real life with a new job at a different company.

Comment: so, when you put references in your CV/resume, do you always avoid putting your current manager as a reference? what if this is your only available reference because you don't have any previous job experience?

Comment: I don't put references in my resume (that's a whole different topic).  But if I did, I wouldn't include my current manager.

Comment: i could open a new topic for this yes

Comment: Downvoter care to comment?

Answer (score 5):

If the job is in the same company then you can not really refuse.  The request is more of a courtesy to allow you to notify your manager before they get a call from your prospective manager.  The manager is going to contact your manager at some point.  For that reason I recommend always talking with your manager before you ever apply for an internal position.  Best case your manager supports you and helps you get into that position.  Worst case your manager decides not to support your move and tells that to the prospective manager.  Your manager is going to do that any way but by letting him/her know ahead of time, gives them the chance to be the good guy out front of your move rather than reacting to something you already put in motion.